# Tcolorbox gives error when using crefname, specifying label as a phantom option

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref

The following code doesn't use the `crefname` option.  In the output only the theorem counter appears as the result of the `cref` call but it doesn't get prepended with the word  `theorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[crefname={theorem}{theorems}]
{thm}{Theorem}{}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[phantom=\label{thm:1}]{}{}
  $1+1=2$.
\end{thm}
This is \cref{thm:1}.
\end{document}
```

I also tried to specify `crefname` as a `cleveref` command, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{thm}{Theorem}{}{}
\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[phantom=\label{thm:1}]{}{}
  $1+1=2$.
\end{thm}
This is \cref{thm:1}.
\end{document}
```

But I get this error:

```
LaTeX Warning: cref  reference format for label type `tcb@cnt@thm' undefined on
 input line 12.
```

Comment: `crefname={theorem}{theorems}` is a key, not `\crefname{theorem}{theorems}` which is interpreted as key name, but is not defined (as pgfkey) as well as `label={thm:1}`, no need to use `phantom=` here, in my point of view

Comment: `labels` is the  wrong tag

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand either of these comments.  I have no idea why neither of the ways I specify (following documentation) `crefname` work.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the correct usage for labeling `tcolorbox` environments **should** use the `label` key.

Second: Using numbers in label names might become tedious as soon the order of the labeled entities changes. Don't use them.

Third: The correct `crefname` option usage is

`crefname={theorem}{theorems}`

i.e. specifying it as a key, not as a macro call `\crefname{foo}{bar}` in the init - slot of the `newtcbtheorem` definition

Using `phantom=\label{thm:1}` is possible, but the counter name is `tcb@cnt@thm` then (since the theorem environment is named `thm`), this value is then stored as being the counter that is labeled with `thm:1`, which leads to an unknown reference with `\cref`, looking for `tcb@cnt@thm` as reference format but this is not known.

One way is to overwrite the label information which is an `cleveref` feature, with the optional argument to `\label`:

`phantom={\label[thm]{thm:1}}`

This is awkward, of course, but the cause of not using `label=thm:1` directly.

A better possible solution is to define the counter, say `thmagain` before (eventually use `\crefname{thmagain}{foo}{bar}` as well) and say `use counter=thmagain` in the init slot of the theorem definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\newcounter{thmagain}

\newtcbtheorem[crefname={theorem}{theorems}]{thm}{Theorem}{}{}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=thmagain,crefname={improved theorem}{improved theorems}]{thmagain}{Theorem}{}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[phantom={\label[thm]{thm:1}}]{}{}
  $1+1=2$.
\end{thm}
This is \cref{thm:1}.


\begin{thmagain}[phantom={\label{thmagainstuff}}]{}{}
  $1+1=2$.
\end{thmagain}
This is \cref{thmagainstuff}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `label` key of `tcolorbox` is nonstandard as far as I know, and it breaks the way my editor `Emacs` handles references.  The issues, including why simple numbers are used in labels,  are explained in the post [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372554/tcolorbox-theorem-labeling-scheme-messes-up-editors-reference-mechanism](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372554/tcolorbox-theorem-labeling-scheme-messes-up-editors-reference-mechanism)

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo in the specification of the `crefname` option to `\newtcbtheorem`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MátéWierdl: Sorry, `label=` is standard, it's only hidden to Emacs. My solution is a valid LaTeX solution and not for Emacs/vim etc. I work with Emacs, but I don't need it's reference features.

Comment: @MátéWierdl: And `does not work` is no useful description -- see the screen shot, it works, with ordinary pdflatex compilation two times

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I changed my original post, and it explains what "doesn't work" exactly is. The `label=` option doesn't seem standard for other latex environments. For example,  if I define a theoremlike environment with  `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` then I get an error if I have `\begin[label=one]{thm}`.  The `Emacs` developers are extremely responsive to requests, but they won't implement something which appears to be in a single latex environment.  Is the `label=` option planned to be in the next latex standard?

Comment: `label=` is used by `tcolorbox`, `listings`, `enumitem` and is in fact a good approach. `Emacs` has to follow it's support after LaTeX (since being the secondary software here) not vice versa.

Comment: Actually, your second example, so the "improved theorem" stuff works well with `Emacs` as well.  Thanks a lot!!!